# Missing word in VOA news：US Government Panel Says Consider Environment in Diet

Tags: word-choice, listening

I don't know whether it's suitable to ask this kind of question here. I just got some listening issues. I can't identify the word missing in the sentence No.1 in this metioned VOA and want to make sure if the sentences No.2 & 3 are correct.

Really hope someone can help me and thank you very very much!

Below is the link: （VOA news: US Government Panel Says Consider Environment in Diet）
http://www.voanews.com/content/government-panel-says-consider-the-environment-in-diet/2673305.html

0'50'' 1. What you eat has consequences, not only for your  ???  but on the planet.

1'04'' 2. "Meat production is very carbon intensive, I mean it, It releases greenhouse gases..."

2'18'' 3. ...or falling in industrialized countries...

Thank you very very much!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ELU isn't a transcription service. FWIW, *...it releases greenhouse gases that are warming the planet ... and so if you're concerned about climate change ...um you realise that you need to start eating lower on the food chain to reduce your overall ...um your overall carbon footprint.* Etc., etc...

Comment: Thank you, @FumbleFingers. But I think ELU is place  where people can get help regarding the questions or confusions on every aspect of English. so I asked the question here. If you have a better place for this kind of listening question, could you please tell me? Thanks

Comment: I don't know of any sites *deliberately intending* to provide a free transcription service. I don't think it's a good way to learn English anyway, so I doubt many organisations would be interested in funding anything like that. Having said that, Marius did apparently answer your specific questions here (though I'd rather it had been via a *comment* than an *answer*, and I'd like to *delete* the question now, because it has little relevance to future visitors). You might find [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) useful, but not for basic transcription services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 for your **waistline**

2 and 3 are OK